# Изменить текст и ссылку на кнопке

Tags: javascript, html, button

Использую PWA приложение и при выполнении скрипта install() - предлагается окно добавления приложения на рабочий стол. В идеале, после того как человек добавил приложение - необходимо заменить текст Install на Open и добавить ссылку на эту кнопку. Как это можно сделать?

```html
<button onclick="install();fbq('track', 'Lead');" type="button"  class="text-capitalize v-btn v-btn--block theme--dark" style="background-color: rgb(1, 135, 95) !important; border-color: rgb(1, 135, 95);">
                                                
  <div  id="first" class="v-btn__content">

  Install

  </div>

</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смена содержимого:

```
document.getElementById("first").innerHTML = "Open";
```

Добавление ссылки:

```
var myDom = document.getElementById("first");
myDom.addEventListener("click", function() {
window.location.href = yourURL;
});
```